# Second Largest Element In an Array

Tags: java, arrays

Here, if I do not consider time complexity and space complexity criteria in mind, I tried something.
Here, **largest** represents the **largest element** in array and once largest was found, I **swapped** the **largest with the first element** of the array and then so I reused the method which I used to find **largest** in order to get the **second largest** method which I have stored in **secondLargest** variable.
Here, Ideally I should get the **secondl̥argest** element in return while I am **getting the largest**.
**PLEASE HELP**

```
public static int secondLargest(int[] arr, int size)
{
    int largest= arr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]> largest)
        {
            largest= arr[i];
        }
        
        
    }
     if(largest!= arr[0])
     {
        int temp= arr[0];
        arr[0]= largest;
        largest = temp;
     }
     int SecondLargest = arr[1];
     for(int i=2; i<size; i++)
     {
         if(arr[i]> SecondLargest)
         {
             SecondLargest= arr[i];
         }
         
     }
     return SecondLargest;
```

Comment: Do it in one loop. Initialize  max and secondMax with Integer.MIN_VALUE.  then loop  array and if arr[i] bigger than max, than secondMax=max; max = arr[i]; else if arr[i] bigger than secondMax just secondMax=arr[i]. I didn't written code, as I assume you are practicing so give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

> I swapped the largest with the first element of the array

Well, not exactly. You copied the value of the largest element to a variable named `largest`. Then you swapped the value of this variable with the value of the first element of the array. The array-element that holds the largest value remains untouched.

You've to store the index of the array element that holds the largest value, then you can swap:

```
public static int secondLargest(int[] arr, int size)
{
    int largestIx = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if(arr[i] > arr[largestIx]) {
            largestIx = i;
        }
    }

    int temp = arr[0];
    arr[0] = arr[largestIx];
    arr[largestIx] = temp;
    ...
```